# How to Show All Button Click In All PLace Data In Marker In Drop in Google Map In Ios

Tags: ios, google-maps, marker

How to Show All In All Data in pin on Map view controller?

Here is my code:

Datalist.m

```
-(IBAction)ShowAll:(id)sender
{
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    mapviewobj = [story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MapViewController"];
    click = YES;
    [mapviewobj setmyarry:arrdatalist];
    mapviewobj.myclick=click;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mapviewobj animated:YES];

}
```

MapViewcontroller.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{

cameraPath = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:strLat.doubleValue longitude:strLong.doubleValue  zoom:17];

mapView=[[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:mapView.frame];

mapView.camera=cameraPath;

self.view=mapView;
marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];

marker.position = cameraPath.target;

marker.title=strName;

marker.snippet = strAdd;

marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;

marker.map = mapView;

mapView.delegate=self;

GMSPolyline *polyline = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:[GMSPath pathFromEncodedPath:strPoint]];
        polyline.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        polyline.strokeWidth = 5.f;
        polyline.map = mapView;
        self.view=mapView;


        mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        [mapView animateToLocation:currentLocation];


        marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = currentLocation;
        marker.title=@"You are Here";
        marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];

        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
        marker.map = mapView;

}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    if (myclick)
    {

       for (int i=0; i<arrdata.count; i++)
       {


           strLat=[[[[arrdata objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lat"];
           strLong=[[[[arrdata objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"geometry"]objectForKey:@"location"]objectForKey:@"lng"];
           strAdd=[[arrdata objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
           NSLog(@"\n%@ Lat: %f Long: %f",strAdd,strLat.doubleValue,strLong.doubleValue);
           cameraPath = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:strLat.doubleValue longitude:strLong.doubleValue  zoom:17];
           mapView=[[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:mapView.frame];
           mapView.camera=cameraPath;
           marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
           marker.position = cameraPath.target;
           marker.title=strName;
           marker.snippet = strAdd;

           [mapView animateToLocation:currentLocation];

           CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([strLat doubleValue], [strLong doubleValue]);
           marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
//           marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([strLat doubleValue], [strLong doubleValue]);
           GMSMarker *location = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
           location.title=@"You are Here";
           location.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"green"];
           mapView.delegate=self;

           location.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;

           location.map = mapView;

    }
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your issue with more detail? also what is your `myclick` and `click` properties?